# Google analytics userType by date in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics

I'm using https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics/ to get google analytics data in laravel.

I want to know: Is there any way to collect user type by date for 3 days?

## Logic

get `fetchUserTypes` by dates

## Example

```
18/1/2019 - Returned Users 100 - New Users 20
17/1/2019 - Returned Users 30 - New Users 11
16/1/2019 - Returned Users 19 - New Users 7

and today is 19/1/2019
```

## Code

This is default code which returns `sum` data of last 3 days, what I want is same thing but separate for each day.

```
$analyticsData6 = Analytics::fetchUserTypes(Period::days(3));
```

## Dump data

This is what code above returns

```
Collection {#3829 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "type" => "New Visitor"
      "sessions" => 20
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "type" => "Returning Visitor"
      "sessions" => 11
    ]
  ]
}
```

What I want is to get something similar like:

```
Collection {#3829 ▼
  #OneDayBefore: array:2 [▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        "type" => "New Visitor"
        "sessions" => 100
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        "type" => "Returning Visitor"
        "sessions" => 20
      ]
    ]
  ],
  #TwoDaysBefore: array:2 [▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        "type" => "New Visitor"
        "sessions" => 30
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        "type" => "Returning Visitor"
        "sessions" => 11
      ]
    ]
  ],
  #ThreeDaysBefore: array:2 [▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        "type" => "New Visitor"
        "sessions" => 19
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        "type" => "Returning Visitor"
        "sessions" => 7
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

> PS: Don't go with `OneDayBefore, TwoDaysBefore, ThreeDaysBefore`
>   arrays I just made-up those to give you my point.

Can that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solved

This code does what I wanted

```
$analyticsDatas6 = Analytics::performQuery(
  Period::days(2),
  ' ga:userType',
  [
   'metrics' => 'ga:sessions, ga:pageviews',
   'dimensions' => 'ga:date'
  ]
);
```

In case you want to use this code in charts you have to return it into json then you're able to use it i jQuery, just add this line after code above and you're good to go:

```
$analyticsData6 = json_encode($analyticsDatas6, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES );
```

Hope it helps.